# Как можно реализовать такое перетаскивание страницы?

Tags: java, android

[image]

если кто знает помогите, буду рад!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Держите пример похожей анимации, только анимация идет с другого бока:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932462/animate-the-transition-between-fragments